# Git repo does not have a .htaccess file, how do I create a local .htaccess that will not be removed by git pull --rebase

Tags: git, .htaccess, github

The title might be a bit weird explanation of things so I will go into more detail here.

I have set up git repo trough github for a website so all of us can edit on our own computers and then push changes to the webserver. I then have a pull script on my website that does `git pull --rebase` every few minutes, if there are changes in the repo.

Now, I do not wish to have the username and password for the database on github, so I was thinking of having a .htaccess file locally on the server that holds the username and password instead of having it in the php files. So I created a .htaccess file locally, and added .htaccess in gitignore and gitattributes, but whenever I do a `git pull --rebase` the updates to the .htaccess file are removed. And if I do `git rm .htaccess` and `git status` it says that .htaccess has been deleted and that I have to push the file to the repo, even though the repo does not have any .htaccess file. And I can't push either because the server version of the repo is read-only.

Any ideas?

Update with .gitignore file:
    #################
    ## Eclipse
    #################

```
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath


#################
## Visual Studio
#################

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.vspscc
.builds
*.dotCover

## TODO: If you have NuGet Package Restore enabled, uncomment this
#packages/

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish

# Others
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
sql
TestResults
*.Cache
ClientBin
stylecop.*
~$*
*.dbmdl
Generated_Code #added for RIA/Silverlight projects

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML



############
## Windows
############

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini


#############
## Python
#############

*.py[co]

# Packages
*.egg
*.egg-info
dist
build
eggs
parts
bin
var
sdist
develop-eggs
.installed.cfg

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
.coverage
.tox

#Translations
*.mo

#Mr Developer
.mr.developer.cfg

# Mac crap
.DS_Store

#################
## Project specific
#################

# Ignore htcaccess so so pwd is not public
.htaccess

# Ignore the pull script because this is only for the server
pull.php
```

Comment: Please show your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I added the gitignore now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution (I hope) from this post on stackoverflow: [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

And the line that did it for me was: `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`

Answer (score 0):

Github just doesn't support uploading the htacess file, but you can still add the htaccess file manually in github

**1. Go to the repository where you want to add the htacess file**

**2. Click `Add file`-`Create new file`**

**3. Open your file .htaccess and copy all the contents of your htaccess file and paste it into the 'Edit new file' section. All you have to do is enter the file name `.htaccess`, enter the commit name as you wish and then commit**